# Adding data to empty rickshaw chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, rickshaw

I am charting different data with RickshawJS. But I need a way to update the chart when a user clicks the `#search` button. Right now it just creates a new chart below the old one, and that is pretty messy.

The user enters the page and enters some details and clicks the button to chart it. So ideally I'd like to start with an empty chart that isn't shown, but I can't really figure out how to remove the data from the chart and axes and then update it.

I could call `$('#chart svg').remove();` on the chart and axes but it seems messy.

```
$('#search').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = utils.malletData();
    var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
            element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
            width: 800,
            height: 250,
            series: [ {
                    name: data['name'],
                    color: 'steelblue',
                    data: data['series']
            } ]
    } );
    graph.render();

    var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( {
        graph: graph,
        xFormatter: function(x) {
            var date = new Date(x).getTime();
            return moment(x).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
        },
        yFormatter: function(y) { return Math.floor(y) + " users" }
    } );

    var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X( {
        graph: graph,
        orientation: 'bottom',
        element: document.getElementById('x_axis'),
        tickFormat: function(x) { return moment(x).fromNow(); },
        ticks: 7,
        tickSize: 1,
    } );
    xAxis.render();

    var ticksTreatment = 'glow';
    var yAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
        graph: graph,
        orientation: 'left',
        tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
        ticksTreatment: ticksTreatment,
        element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
    } );
    yAxis.render();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no official way to do so. However, you could leverage the fact that arrays in javascript are passed by reference and then update the graph.

Have a look at this [demo on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWXzL/1/)

```
var data = [
        {
            data: [ { x: 0, y: 120 }, { x: 1, y: 890 }, { x: 2, y: 38 }, { x: 3, y: 70 }, { x: 4, y: 32 } ],
            color: "#c05020"
        }, {
            data: [ { x: 0, y: 80 }, { x: 1, y: 200 }, { x: 2, y: 100 }, { x: 3, y: 520 }, { x: 4, y: 133 } ],
            color: "#30c020"
        }
];


var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.getElementById("chart"),
    renderer: 'line',
    height: 300,
    width: 800,
    series: data
} );

var y_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
    graph: graph,
    orientation: 'left',
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
    element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
} );

graph.render();


$('button#add').click(function() {
    data.push({
            data: [ { x: 0, y: 200 }, { x: 1, y: 390 }, { x: 2, y: 1000 }, { x: 3, y: 200 }, { x: 4, y: 230 } ],
            color: "#6060c0"
    });
    graph.update();
});
```